# Is heart rate indicative of sleep phase?

Tags: sleep, cardiology

Lately I've been using an alarm clock that determines what phase of sleep you are in (light or deep) so that it waits until you are at a lighter sleep phase before waking you up.

It does this by using the microphone and motion sensors to determine if you are moving around or not.

I was wondering if there were a more accurate method of determining this and I was thinking that maybe the person's heart rate would have a noticeable difference between the different sleep phases, is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

To have a really precise way to determine the sleep phase you must be under [EEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) beacuse HR is much more influenced by circadian rhythms as you can [read here](http://hyper.ahajournals.org/content/18/2/199).

Comment: Hi! Excellent point. Though, I think you should contrast your answer by taking into account those two studies/reviews suggesting that HR might also vary according to the sleep cycle (NREM/REM). http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12738405 and http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3797399/. Thanks. BW